# Linking a library that not have a standarized name/extension

Tags: c++, linker, cmake

If you use the command [target_link_libraries](http://www.cmake.org/cmake/help/v3.0/command/target_link_libraries.html) in cmake, when linking the linker will search for libraries which name match some criteria. For instace:

Using following command:

```
target_link_libraries(some_target  some_lib)
```

In Linux the linker will search for: **libsome_lib.so** while in Windows the linker will search for **some_lib.lib** (in Windows I'm compiling a VS project generated from the cmake project).

Due to deployment requirements of my application the libraries have no extension and have to be called the same in both OS (e.g `some_lib`).

How can I tell cmake that search for such library?

<del>I suppose that entering the full path will do the trick, but</del>, there is <del>another</del> any way to do this?

**Edit:**  Specifying the full path to the library does not work.

Comment: Point is you are not supposed to link with the library name anymore, you are supposed to pass the output of `find_package` if it is an external library, the target name if it is built in the current project, or simply write `namespace::lib` if you use cmake > 3.0 (that will also add the include paths and defines). Are you sure that `find_package` et similia is not applicable in your case?

Comment: @sbabbi I was reading about `find_package` and it seems to I will have to write my custom "package finder" in order to find my libs. It is more work than I want to do, but until now is the only solution it seems to work.

Answer (score 1):

I didn't ever test that, but the [CMake Wiki Docs](http://www.cmake.org/Wiki/CMake_Useful_Variables) refer these variables to specify library extensions:

> ```
> CMAKE_FIND_LIBRARY_SUFFIXES 
> CMAKE_IMPORT_LIBRARY_SUFFIX
> ```
>
> Windows-specific. Appears to be read-only. Use `SET_TARGET_PROPERTIES`.
>
> ```
> CMAKE_LINK_LIBRARY_SUFFIX
> ```
>
> Windows-specific.
>
> ```
> CMAKE_SHARED_LIBRARY_SUFFIX
> ```
>
> Appears to be read-only. Use `SET_TARGET_PROPERTIES`.
>
> ```
> CMAKE_STATIC_LIBRARY_SUFFIX
> ```
>
> Appears to be read-only. Use `SET_TARGET_PROPERTIES`.

Comment: It does not work on Windows, I've not tried in linux since I need something working in both OS. On the other hand I couldn't see how to use `SET_TARGET_PROPERTIES` in order to change the read-only property of these variables for Windows.  

Any way thanks.